# Django Rest Framework Camel Case - Testing not using parser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple REST API in Django using rest_framework.  I added the djangorestframework-camel-case plugin and updated my REST_FRAMEWORK configuration and the REST API outputs proper camelCase.  However, when I test using unittest (`python manage.py test app.test`), the results are in snake_case instead of camelCase and cause my assertions to fail.

Using this fork: https://github.com/rense/djangorestframework-camel-case

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend', 'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter'),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': ('djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',),
    'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',),
    'TEST_REQUEST_PARSER_CLASSES': ('djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
}
```

Do I need to add some additional configuration?  Is this a bug in djangorestframework?  In djangorestframework-camel-case?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. From my current investigations, the renderer IS called and returns the correct output, but for some reason this is ignored, so I'd be tempted to say that it's a bug in Django Rest Framework.
Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @ameunier I was not able to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

The problem might be in your test file.

Let's say you have in your tests something among the lines of:

`client = APIClient()
response = client.get('some_url', format='json')`

The response object will have a `data` parameter which will be snake_case, and a `content` which will be camelCase.

`response.data # will contain snake_case keys
json.loads(response.content) # will contain camelCase keys`

Make sure you are running your assertions against the right response parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned you can also set this globally, which may be what you want:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

as per docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#configuration